# How to use TailwindCSS with Vite? (not react or something just vanilla JS)

Tags: html, css, npm, tailwind-css, vite

I'm a **newbie** and I'm gonna lose my mind. I watch every tutorial and read every documents. It's just not work. Anyone knows **how to mix tailwind(postcss or cli) and vite** ?

I want to use **vanilla css with vite, and some tailwind at the same time**. But it's recommended not to use tailwindcss CDN with vite.

First I'm creating my vanilla js project with vite and than trying to install tailwind and I do every step as they said. Then I prompt **npm run dev** *voila* error

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? You should be able to install Tailwind CSS [as per their installation instructions for Vite](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) while ignoring the React-specific bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following commands to create a new Vite project: select Vanilla then Javascript

```
npm init vite@latest my-vite-project
```

select Vanilla , Enter then select JavaScript

```
cd my-vite-project
```

then Install npm

```
npm install
```

Install Tailwind CSS and its dependencies using npm:

```
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

npx tailwindcss init -p

Create a postcss.config.js file in the root of your project to configure PostCSS:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

now run your project

```
npm run dev
```